# XCode7 Unit tests fail (compiler error)

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xcode7

I have created a Unit Test target AFTER my app was already created.

The problem i have is that the test will fail with compiler errors unless i manually add each .swift file and library to the testing target. Since my app is a rather large app with many files and library dependencies this seems rather difficult to do.

I have followed the advice on this post http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/ which suggests that XCode can do this by setting the "Bundle Loader" and "Test host" settings in the testing target and setting "Symbols Hidden By Default" to NO in the app target, but that doesn't work.

What is the right way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `@testable import YourModule` and then all your classes should be available in your test case file.

You can read a little bit more [here](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-2-xcode-7-unit-testing-access/) and some Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html).